# How to remove the first and last character from a file using batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is my input file content which I am using to copy to the output file.

```
#sdfs|dfasf|sdfs|
sdfs|df!@$%%*&!sdffs|
sasdfasfa|dfsdf|#sdfs|
```

What I need to do is to omit the first character '#' and last character '|' in the output file.
So the output will be,

```
sdfs|dfasf|sdfs|
sdfs|df!@$%%*&!sdffs|
sasdfasfa|dfsdf|#sdfs
```

Batch script is new to me, but I tried my best and tried these codes,

```
:: drop first and last char

@echo off > xyz.txt & setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (E:\abc1.txt) do (
set str=%%a
set str=!str:~1!
echo !str!>> xyz.txt
)
```

As you can see it is not able to produce the required output.

The output now being produced is like

```
sdfs|dfasf|sdfs|
dfs|dfsdffs|
asdfasfa|dfsdf|#sdfs|
```

I don't know why the string `!@$%%*&!` is also getting ripped !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next script, call file **far.vbs**, anf create your new file.
Code:

```
set OldFile=E:\abc1.txt
set NewFile=E:\xyz.txt
echo. > "%NewFile%"
start far.vbs "%NewFile%" "%OldFile%"
```

**far.vbs** — delete first and last char from file.
Create new file **far.vbs** in the same folder as first script, and paste the following code:

```
Set OldFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set rdOldFile = OldFile.OpenTextFile(Wscript.Arguments(1), 1)
oContent = rdOldFile.ReadAll
rdOldFile.Close

Set lOldFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set lrdOldFile = OldFile.OpenTextFile(Wscript.Arguments(1), 1)
oLen = len(lrdOldFile.ReadAll)
lrdOldFile.Close

oData = oContent
oData = Right(oContent, oLen-1)
oData = Left(oData, oLen-2)

Set NewFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fData = NewFile.OpenTextFile(Wscript.Arguments(0), 2)
fData.WriteLine (oData)
fData.Close
```

Comment: you mean .. should I add this to some other piece of code? I am a newbie in Batch script .. I hardly understand something about it. pls post all working code. Thank you.

Comment: @B7ackAnge7z, I don't know why, the bat also removes !@$%%*&! string, This is what the same problem I was facing with my scripts too, thanx for the response.

Comment: Script removes text between !someText!, because ! is used by variables. Now I changed code script. Try it. Does work fine.

Comment: @B7ackAnge7z, works all fine.. thanx :-) btw I just want to confirm, does this script work if I don't have .Net or Visual-Studio, installed?

Comment: +1 for a good technique, otherwise, I had come to conclusion, that its not possible.

Comment: I am glad, that could help you. Best regards ;)

Answer (score 2):

I can't debug my code right now, but try:

```
:: drop first and last char

@echo off > xyz.txt
@echo off > xyz2.txt
@echo off > xyz3.txt

setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (E:\abc1.txt) do (
set /a N+=1
echo %%a >> xyz.txt
echo %%b >> xyz2.txt
echo %%%c >> xyz3.txt
```

Comment: btw, this is what the output I am getting :: `~1,-1
~1,-1
~1,-1`

Comment: plz give me some feedback on what kind of output my code produces, then i'll adapt the code accordingly

Comment: well. This is the output now .. "ECHO is off.
#sdfs|dfasf|sdfs|
sdfs|dfsdffs|"

Comment: @lugte098, its ok .. pls take your time,

Comment: @lugte098, nope, same as previous o/p.

Comment: im curious what this piece of code gives you as output. Does it give you 3 seperate file, with each 1 line of code?

Comment: @lugte098, output is one file, the content is "ECHO is off.[new_line] #sdfs|dfasf|sdfs| [new_line] sdfs|dfsdffs|

Comment: @lugte098, Implemented code from @B7ackAnge7z, thanx for the interaction. +1

Answer (score 2):

batch is never a strong point for file processing and text manipulation. If you have the luxury, you can download [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) from GNU win32, then use this one liner.

```
C:\test>sed  "/#/{s/^#//;s/|$//}" file
sdfs|dfasf|sdfs
sdfs|df!@$%%*&!sdffs|
sasdfasfa|dfsdf|#sdfs
```